# How to pass a string from C to swift?

Tags: c, swift

I am using OpenSSL as a library in swift. Since it's in C, I need to pass some data from C language back to swift. The data was an array, but after some research I have learned that I cannot pass an array from C to swift. One way I can think of it is to change the array into a string, an then pass the string back to swift. 
In C I wrote:

```
char teststring()
{
    char c[]={"H","E","L","L","O"};
    printf(c);
    return c;
}
```

In Swift I wrote:

```
teststring()
```

The result is that it only prints `H`.
What did I do wrong with it? It there a easier way to pass an array from C back to Swift?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to change

```
char c[]={"H","E","L","L","O"};
```

to

```
char c[]={'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};
```

Or

```
char c[]="HELLO";
```

By `char c[]={"H","E","L","L","O"};` an array of strings is getting declared, rather than an array of characters.
There is a difference between a string and a char.

A string literal enclosed within a double quotes represents a set of characters. So, "H" seems to represent a single character to you, but internally it contains an additional character with `'H'` and the very necessary `'\0'` which is terminating character in C. That was possibly the reason that you were getting a `H` printed on your console as output.

This is because as per [C11 standard - Section: 6.4.5 String literals](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) which states,

> A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz". A UTF-8 string literal is the same, except prefixed by u8. A wide string literal is the same, except prefixed by the letter L, u, or U.

Additionally, section: 6.4.4.4 Character constants states that,

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in 'x'. A wide character constant is the same, except prefixed by the letter L, u, or U. With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution character set.

Also,

```
char teststring()
```

means that `teststring` is supposed to return a `char`, and you are returning `c` which is now a string. So either change it to return a pointer to `char` i.e

```
char* teststring()
```

Or, return a `char` like `return c[0];`

Answer (score 1):

there's a couple things...

First, it'd be a lot easier to format your string this way:

```
char* c="HELLO";
```

But, if you want to do it your way still, you need to null-terminate your string, otherwise the computer will not know where the string ends and new memory begins:

```
char c[]={"H","E","L","L","O"};
```

becomes:

```
char c[]={'H','E','L','L','O',0};
```

See the single quotes vs the double quotes?  The double quotes indicate a whole string (null terminated with zero)... the single quotes indicate a single char.

So when you did it with double quotes, in characters in memory for the whole thing looked something like this:

H0E0L0L0O0

With single quotes, the characters in memory looks like this:

HELLO0

The printf function will print until it hits a zero and then quit.  That's why you were getting just the 'H' printing out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to declare array of `char`s.

So the it will be

#### Case-1

```
char c[]={'H','E','L','L','O','\0');
```

Here you have created something like array of array of chars. Coorect way of doing it would be.

#### Case-2

```
char c[][2]={"H","E","L","L","O"};
```

*But in this case you have to pass `c[0]` or `c[1]` in `printf`.*

Also note that the first thing can alternatively done using

#### Case-3

```
   char c[]="HELLO";
```

This is an array of 6 characters, `\0` included.

And once again you could have also done

#### Case-4

```
   char *c[]={"H","E","L","L","O"};
```

Here you have to pass the `c[0]` or `c[1]` which will print the string `"H"` or `"E"`.

Also note that

```
char c[]={'H','E','L','L','O'};
```

is a valid initialization but this is not null terminated. So you can't pass it where a null terminated char array is expected. (like `strlen()` etc).

Now the case-2, here the strings are modifiable. So you can change the character in them where as the strings in case-4 are not. Those are string literals which are non-modifiable.

> Simply put if you wanted to have a string which contains those as
> characters then Case-1 and case-3 are the way for you.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is an array and when you return `c` you return first element. You need to return entire array. Check

```
printf("%s", c);
return *c;
```

And remember to change signature of your function